# Какой файл css имеет больший приоритет?

Tags: html, css

коллеги.

В проекте есть два файла со стилями css. Какой порядок подключения должен быть - какой файл должен быть в head выше/ниже, что бы он имел больший приоритет?

Спасибо

Comment: Чем НИЖЕ тем ВЫШЕ приоритет. Точнее не приоритет, а то, что стили применяются тем позднее, чем файл объявлен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здраствуйте. Наибольший приоритет выше будет у последнего добавленного.

Comment: Благодарю!!!!!!